# How to format output from php form to html email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, formatting

Firstly I am not a programmer - so I am trying to adapt things to what I need. I have been working for some weeks on a html form that produces a unique code and emails the data to me and the form owner.

I have managed to get all this to work and build it into my website.

However the last vestige is that I want to format the email into html and I have searched and read and tried many different pieces of code for this - some even from here with no success. I ether get code, nothing or all the info in one uninterrupted sentence.

Here is my php. Near the bottom is the info I need in the mail at `$email_message`

Form code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:546px;width:350px;height:84px;">
<style type="text/css">
.formtxt{color:white;}
</style>
<?php
$tokens = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

$serial = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
    $serial .= $tokens[rand(0, 35)];
}

if ($i < 2) {
    $serial .= '-';
}
}
?>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="bridalcontact.php">
<table width="350px" align="center">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name"> <span class="formtxt">First Name*</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name"> <span class="formtxt">Last Name*</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email"> <span class="formtxt">Email*</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="security"> <span class="formtxt">What colour is the sky *</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="middle">
<input type="text" name="security" maxlength="80" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone">Code</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="disabled" name="code" size="20" value='<?php echo "$serial"?>'readonly>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to = "my email address here";
  $email_subject = "Your AODJ voucher";
  function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.    ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
  }
  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['security'])) {
      died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
  $security = $_POST['security']; // required
  $code = $_POST['code']; // not required
  $error_message = "";
  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  $security_exp = "/blue/";
  if(!preg_match($security_exp,$security)) {
    $error_message .= 'Wrong solar system - sorry.<br />';
  }
  //$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  //if(!preg_match($security_exp,$security)) {
  //$error_message .= 'Wrong solar system - sorry.<br />';
  //}
  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }
  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
  $email_message .= "code: ".clean_string($code)."\n";
  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
  @mail($email_from, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
<?php
  if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
    header( "Location: bridaloptionsthanks.html" ) ; exit ;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: learn html. apply knowledge.

Comment: We've all got to start somewhere. First, get rid of the @ signs. They're swallowing errors that you might need to see. Second, you can call mail once and BCC it to yourself if you'd like. I'd change all those `\n` to `\r\n`. Also add `\r\n` after the <br> tags and ditch the `/` that's in the <br>. What do you want the HTML to look like? Just line breaks? This was the first result when I googled php sending html email: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: You'll never get anything sent to output in HTML with your edits until you add `$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";`

Comment: I guess basically just a table that i can format background colour and that pulls in the form data at this stage. If I can get that far I can play as I do with getting the rest.

Comment: You should add your form code.

Comment: "You should add your form code."
Done Fred.:-)

Comment: Check my new answer below, worked ok for me. Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Check out the link above that `mkaatman` included if that's what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send mail formatted in HTML, you will need to add the proper header information.

Change this line:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
...
```

to this: (and adding a dot/concatenate `$headers .=`)

```
$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
...
```

Sidenote: Only the first header line does not have a dot/concatenate. Other headers following it will require it. Consult the manual on PHP.net

Then add your HTML where you wish.

As per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have on the occasions i've tried the html used those headers with no success.
I have a antispam validation in the "security" requiring a particular answer. I thought this was satisfactory??

Comment: The rest I will have to try when I am home and can work on the code again.
I guess If I could just get the very basic html to come through - I can then format it how I want by playing with the code. But i just don't seem to be able to get off the starting block :-(

Answer (score 1):

Providing a full code to send your email as html could be a long work depending what you want.

1. In your code, I have to mention you that you have might have a security issue since you allow your server to send email from a form with no validation. In some way, someone could use your server to send spam by automating the post from your script.
2. email could be send in html according mime formats which could be quite complex to implement if you want to support multipart content (one version in plain text and one version in html). Fortunately most clients supports html today.
3. If you want to send a beautiful html content well designed and so one, you must learn html and css. You should be aware to mail clients, do not always supports all css attributes, which make development a bit long.

Comment: Here is a simple way to send multipart content: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=142893

Comment: yeah thanks elefantphace I new someone would come back with that,

Comment: I think I have done pretty well so far myself for someone who has never been taught coding. At least I gave it a fair shot first.

Answer (score 1):

*Tested and works fine for me. Give this a try.*

**[FORM]**

```
<?php
$tokens = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

$serial = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
    $serial .= $tokens[rand(0, 35)];
}

if ($i < 2) {
    $serial .= "-";
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
.formtxt{color:black;}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<h1>My first heading</h1>

<p align="left">My first paragraph</p>

<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:140px;width:350px;height:84px;">
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="bridalcontact.php">
<table width="350px" align="center">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name"><span class="formtxt">First Name*</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name"><span class="formtxt">Last Name*</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email"><span class="formtxt">Email*</span></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">

<label for="security"> <span class="formtxt">What colour is the sky *</span></label>

</td>
<td valign="middle">
<input type="text" name="security" maxlength="80" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone">Code</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="disabled" name="code" size="20" value="<?php echo "$serial"?>"readonly>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[PROCESSING]**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to = "YOUR EMAIL HERE";
  $email_subject = "Your AODJ voucher";
  function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.    ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
  }
  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['security'])) {
      died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
  $security = $_POST['security']; // required
  $code = $_POST['code']; // not required
  $error_message = "";
  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }


  $security_exp = "/blue/";


  if(!preg_match($security_exp,$security)) {

    $error_message .= 'Wrong solar system - sorry.<br />';
  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }
  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
  $email_message .= "code: ".clean_string($code)."\n";

  // create email headers

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
  @mail($email_from, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
<?php
  if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
    header( "Location: thank_you.php" ) ; exit ;
  }
}
?>
```

**[Thank you]**

```
<?php

echo "Thank you";

?>
```

Comment: Hi Fred.
I know the code works as is however I seem unable to inject html into it successfully. Can i ask.... where would you suggest i put this:
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user2138201 I edited the FORM part and changed a few things for testing purposes. The rest, you'll have to learn with tutorials on the Web if it's HTML related.